# keras multi gpu model slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I'm trying the multi_gpu_model in keras. The multi-gpu version is always slower than single-gpu, except the Xception example.

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = Xception(weights=None,
                     input_shape=(height, width, 3),
                     classes=num_classes)
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, n)
parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='rmsprop')
```

For other examples, the 4-gpu version is slower. For mnist_cnn.py, the single-gpu version takes about 3s per epoch while the 4-gpu version takes about 4s per epoch.

I'm using 1 GTX1080 and 3 GTX1070. Tried it using both the tensorflow and the mxnet backends, on Windows 10 and on Ubuntu 18. Using keras 2.2.0 and tensorflow-gpu 1.8.0

**So, how to properly use multi_gpu_model to improve training speed?**

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1],
                            border_mode='valid',
                            input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model = multi_gpu_model(model, 4)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: Could this be a case of GPU starvation? See http://blog.datumbox.com/5-tips-for-multi-gpu-training-with-keras/

Comment: Hey, how did you go with solving this issue? I am experiencing this right now... :(

Comment: @nicoco Thanks for the link. I don't see the starvation pattern though. The GPU utilization is pretty high all the time.

Comment: @KevinUpton I did not solve it yet. Still trying by directly using TensorFlow.

Comment: Try multiplying your batch size by the number of gpus used.